# Hadoop task assignment

Tags: hadoop, task

I got confused about Hadoop task assignment. Assuming we have 5 input data D1,D2,D3,D4,D5 then we have 5 jobs J1,J2,J3,J4,J5 and input data of job J1 is D1 and so on. Now if D1 split to 4 blocks and these blocks are distributed along data center then J1 is also broken to tasks (map and reduce) now how many map and reduce tasks we have for J1? How data locality preserved? Does it mean that mapTask1 needs exactly one data block of D1? Can you give me a good source of explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If D1 is stored in HDFS as 4 blocks, and the input format you are using to read the file can split the file up (gz compressed files for example are not splittable), then you will get 4 map tasks for jobs that use D1 as input.

You can increase / decrease the number of map tasks by amending the `mapred.min.split.size` and `mapred.max.split.size` configuration properties (again assuming your input files are splittable, and your input format supports it too).

As for data locality, when the job is submitted, the locations of blocks for the input file (D1) are acquired from the name node, and the map tasks that are created to run your job retain this information (D1, block 0, located in node1, known as the 'split' information).

When the job tracker comes to schedule your tasks, it will examine what task trackers have free map slots, and then identify (if possible) which tasks for your job have splits whose input data blocks are 'local' to the task tracker.

The number of reduce tasks is up to you to configure.